# User object has no attribute customer

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create cart using django but i am getting this error. while I try to check that the user is authenticated or no i used customer = request.user.customer but it says user has no attribute customer

Here is my views.py

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = OrderModel.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()

    else:
        items = []


    context = {}
    return render(request, 'Home/cart.html', context)
```

here is my models.py

```
class CustomerModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

class OrderModel(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   

class Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

I am stuck here and cant understand what to do.

Comment: This looks useful https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customer-model.html

Answer (score 0):

For the user field of the CustomerModel, you must set "related_name" and "related_query_name" to "customer":

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default='', related_name='customer', related_query_name='customer')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the line `customer = request.user.customer` to `customer = request.user.customermodel` may solve your problem. If you want to use `customer = request.user.customer` add related name to your `CustomerModel`'s field:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default='', related_name='customer')
```

Note: Make sure that your user object has a related profile.
For example add an extra condition to your codes like following:

```
if hasattr(request.user, 'customer'): # If you have related name otherwise use customermodel
    customer = request.user.customer
else:
    # Return a proper message here
```

Because if your user object has no related profile this line of code will raise `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error type.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the "related_name" parameter in your CustomerModel customer field for reverse access

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user", on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default='')
```

if you don't set the related name django will generate  field name + "_set" for the access (user_set in your example)